# returning a list of words after reading a file in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a text file which is named `test.txt`. I want to read it and return a list of all words (with newlines removed) from the file.

This is my current code:

```
def read_words(test.txt):
    open_file = open(words_file, 'r')
    words_list =[]
    contents = open_file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(contents)):
         words_list.append(contents[i].strip('\n'))
    return words_list    
    open_file.close()
```

Running this code produces this list:

```
['hello there how is everything ', 'thank you all', 'again', 'thanks a lot']
```

I want the list to look like this:

```
['hello','there','how','is','everything','thank','you','all','again','thanks','a','lot']
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace the `words_list.append(...)` line in the for loop with the following:

```
words_list.extend(contents[i].split())
```

This will split each line on whitespace characters, and then add each element of the resulting list to `words_list`.

Or as an alternative method for rewriting the entire function as a list comprehension:

```
def read_words(words_file):
    return [word for line in open(words_file, 'r') for word in line.split()]
```

Answer (score 20):

Depending on the size of the file, this seems like it would be as easy as:

```
with open(file) as f:
    words = f.read().split()
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I'd write that:

```
def read_words(words_file):
  with open(words_file, 'r') as f:
    ret = []
    for line in f:
      ret += line.split()
    return ret

print read_words('test.txt')
```

The function can be somewhat shortened by using `itertools`, but I personally find the result less readable:

```
import itertools

def read_words(words_file):
  with open(words_file, 'r') as f:
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f))

print read_words('test.txt')
```

The nice thing about the second version is that it can be made to be entirely generator-based and thus avoid keeping all of the file's words in memory at once.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. Here are a few:

**If you don't care about repeated words**:

```
def getWords(filepath):
    with open('filepath') as f:
        return list(itertools.chain(line.split() for line in f))
```

**If you want to return a list of words in which each word appears only once**:

Note: this does not preserve the order of the words

```
def getWords(filepath):
    with open('filepath') as f:
        return {word for word in line.split() for line in f} # python2.7
        return set((word for word in line.split() for line in f)) # python 2.6
```

**If you want a set --and-- want to preserve the order of words**:

```
def getWords(filepath):
    with open('filepath') as f:
        words = []
        pos = {}
        position = itertools.count()
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                if word not in pos:
                    pos[word] = position.next()
                        words.append(word)
    return sorted(words, key=pos.__getitem__)
```

**If you want a word-frequency dictionary**:

```
def getWords(filepath):
    with open('filepath') as f:
        return collections.Counter(itertools.chain(line.split() for line in file))
```

Hope these help

Answer (score 0):

The actual question has already been answered, but I would like to point out that the line f.close() will not be executed as the function returns before that line. Try writing f.close() before the return statement.