# Removing a space from a list element?

Tags: python, string, file, list

I wanted to remove the spaces from my list element and separate them into different list elements. For example, if I have the list:

```
['Hello world', 'testing', 'testing two']
```

I'd want the list to look like:

```
['Hello', 'world', 'testing', 'testing', 'two']
```

The issue I'm having is that i am reading from a file and I already stripped the newline characters and when I tried to strip the spaces, it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code:

```
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
  words = [line.strip().strip(' ') for line in f]
print words
```

This just prints out what I mentioned previously above, with the list elements still having spaces.

If anyone could help me out, that'd be great! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [returning a list of words after reading a file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259288/returning-a-list-of-words-after-reading-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split()` splits on any white space by default, so you can do the whole file in one easy step.

```
words =  f.read().split()
```

If you want to avoid reading the whole file into memory with `f.read()`:

```
words = [word for line in f for word in line.split()]
```

Comment: I thought about posting this as an answer ... It can have some problems for really big files, but generally these days that's probably not a concern.

Comment: @mgilson:  I thought about the large file issue as well, but figured that if he has enough memory to hold all the words individually, he probably has enough memory for the whole chunk.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
" ".join(list).split(" ")
```

That will join the list together and then split it apart. There are probably somewhat more efficient ways, but this way is simple.

Answer (score 1):

`.strip` only removes stuff from the beginning or end of a string.  What you want is to `split` the sting on whitespace:

```
lines_split = [line.split() for line in f]
```

This will give you a nested list which you can easily flatten.  See for example this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406199/748858) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457215/748858).

My prefered approach here would be to write a simple generator to `yield` a word at a time.  Then you can turn it into a list later if you need to:

```
def get_words(filename):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            for word in line.split():
                yield word
```

There's some magic you can do to condense this down with `itertools`, but this should suffice for now.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.  The simplest way to do what you want looks like this:

```
words = []
with open(fname) as f:
  for line in f:
    words.extend(line.split())
```

and the slightly cleverer method looks like this:

```
import itertools
with open(fname) as f:
  words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l.split() for l in f))
```

I don't know which is faster.  Note that *when called without a separator argument*, `split` effectively does what `strip` does as well as splitting on interior whitespace, so you needn't bother calling `strip` first.

Answer (score 0):

I like Zonedabone's answer. But here is another way:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = ['Hello world', 'testing', 'testing two']
>>> result = list(chain.from_iterable(w.split() for w in l))
# ['Hello', 'world', 'testing', 'testing', 'two']
```

Comment: for what it's worth, `chain.from_iterable(w.split() for w in l)` is generally preferable to `chain(*[...])`.  The latter pretty much gets rid of all of the advantage of using iterable objects in the first place.