# How to make a list of words from a text file? split() function is not working correctly

Tags: python

This is my text file that I am working with, nothing fancy:

```
I AM SAM I AM SAM SAM I AM
```

This is my program so far:

```
file_name = input("Enter the text file :")

f = open(file_name, 'r')

x = f.readlines()




print(x)


f.close()
```

This is the results it brings:

```
['I AM SAM I AM SAM SAM I AM\n']
```

Unfortunately, I need the list to look like this:

```
['I','AM','SAM',"I","AM,"SAM"...]
```

I did some research and tried finding a way, and I used the split function.

x.split()

unfortunately, it did not work. I would get the error "'list' object has no attribute 'split"

So I was wondering if there was a way I could split up the list for the whitespace, when I looked at the python documentation it appeared that split() was the one usually used.... What am I missing?

Comment: You want to call `split()` on the strings, not the list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259288/returning-a-list-of-words-after-reading-a-file-in-python

Comment: Thank you, that was all I needed @Scriptim

Comment: Does this answer your question? [returning a list of words after reading a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259288/returning-a-list-of-words-after-reading-a-file-in-python)

Comment: You should use a context manager to handle that file object.

Comment: `words = f.read().split()`.